# API19 doesn't show Child with layout_height="match_parent" in a RelativeLayout with layout_height="wrap_content" in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RecyclerView that has to inflate the following layout in the ViewHolder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:minWidth="25px"

    android:minHeight="25px"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/imageRelative"

        ....

        ....


    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/premiumBlockerView"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:alpha="0.5"

        android:background="@color/Black"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linearLayout1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The RelativeLayout's content changes (image, video, text, etc.) so I'm not able to know the height (the width is the width of the device).

I have to add a view (my premiumBlockerView LinearLayout) that I will show as semi transparent glass or not depends on content type.

The problem is that the height=match_parent in the premiumBlockerView doesn't work and it is allways zero. So, like others post suggested, I added the layout_alignParent and alignBottom parameters and this work arround solution works propery for APIs greater than 20.

Now the application must to work for API 19 and this work arround doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestion? 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same problem too. I am sorry that i still can not find a perfect solution in RelativeLayout, But you can solve this problem by using **ConstraintLayout** or another layout instead of RelativeLayout.

**Note:**
if you set parent RelativeLayout

> android:layout_height="wrap_content">

and child view

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

in RecylerView.

then the child view will get

> "wrap_content"

instead of match_parent, you can find why by reading source code of RelativeLayout onMeasure method.